# vscode can't open certain folder with remote ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am able to remote-ssh to my vm with vscode, however there are some folder I used to be able to open but now i get ssh timeout, however some other folder works fine.

any idea?

e.g
~/code/folder_a ----ok
~/code/folder_b ----ssh timeout

if I rename folder_b to something else, I then can open it, if I rename it back to folder_b, still get timeout.

Answer (score 18):

At windows client:

- Delete all the folder in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage`

At linux client:

- Delete all the folder in `~/.vscode/workspaceStorage` or `~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage`

Comment: Thanks alot. If you have many directories in there, stop all vscode instances. Then Start and Shutdown the failing one. Then delete just the newest folder. The folder is recreated on next start of vscode

Comment: For VSC Insiders, it's `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code - Insiders\User\workspaceStorage`. Thank you and @Sascha! This has been driving me absolutely nuts!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup

```
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
```

[issue in github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1721#issuecomment-597783966)

Comment: no, it does not work, I think it is folder specific settings, if I rename folder_b to something else, i was able to remote open it.

Comment: @Zhongmin what is the folder called at the moment

Answer (score 0):

yeah, just like @Mickaël Blet said it seems that something wrong happened when vscode write the log in the realted folder. More exactly, if you open the folder according to the time this issue occured, you can see the .vscdb file is larger than ever, it cant be read by vscode extention i assume, thats the key point.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).